# Пробелема с остонавливанем анимации через ClearInterval в игре JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Идея игры в том, что заголовок двигается по странице а игрок пытаеться кликнуть по нему. После трех кликов заголовок остонавливается и меняеться на "you win". В моем случае, заголовок меняеться на "you win" но почему то продолжает двигаться несмотря на то, что я остонавливаю его через clearInterval(moveId);внутри фунции stopFunction();

```js
var direction = "right"
var leftOffset = 0;
var topOffset = 0;
var speed = 100;
var clicks = 3;

var moveHeadingRight = function () {
 $("h1").offset({ left: leftOffset });
 leftOffset++;
 if (leftOffset > 100) {
  direction = "down";
 }
};

var moveHeadingDown = function () {
 $("h1").offset({ top: topOffset })
 topOffset++;
 if (topOffset > 100) {
  direction = "left";
 }
};

var moveHeadingLeft = function () {
 $("h1").offset({ left: leftOffset })
 leftOffset--;
 if (leftOffset === 0) {
  direction = "up"
 }
};

var moveHeadingUp = function () {
 $("h1").offset({ top: topOffset })
 topOffset--;
 if (topOffset === 0) {
  direction = "right"
 }
};
var move = function() {
if (direction === "right") {
 moveHeadingRight();
}

if (direction === "down") {
 moveHeadingDown();
}

if (direction === "left") {
 moveHeadingLeft();
}

if (direction === "up") {
 moveHeadingUp();
}
};

var stopFunction = function() {
 if (clicks === 0) {
  $("h1").text("you win!");
  clearInterval(moveId);
 } else if (clicks > 0) {
  clicks--; 
  speed /= 2
  clearInterval(moveId);
  var moveId = setInterval(move, speed);
 }
};
$("h1").click(stopFunction);
var moveId = setInterval(move, speed);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="main-heading">game</h1>
```

По совету UModel исправил код, не помгло и теперь заголовок не изменяет текст на "you win" по какой то причине, я что то сделал не так?

```js
var direction = "right"
var leftOffset = 0;
var topOffset = 0;
var speed = 100;
var clicks = 3;

var moveHeadingRight = function() {
  $("h1").offset({
    left: leftOffset
  });
  leftOffset++;
  if (leftOffset > 100) {
    direction = "down";
  }
};

var moveHeadingDown = function() {
  $("h1").offset({
    top: topOffset
  })
  topOffset++;
  if (topOffset > 100) {
    direction = "left";
  }
};

var moveHeadingLeft = function() {
  $("h1").offset({
    left: leftOffset
  })
  leftOffset--;
  if (leftOffset === 0) {
    direction = "up"
  }
};

var moveHeadingUp = function() {
  $("h1").offset({
    top: topOffset
  })
  topOffset--;
  if (topOffset === 0) {
    direction = "right"
  }
};
var move = function() {
  if (direction === "right") {
    moveHeadingRight();
  }

  if (direction === "down") {
    moveHeadingDown();
  }

  if (direction === "left") {
    moveHeadingLeft();
  }

  if (direction === "up") {
    moveHeadingUp();
  }
};

var stopFunction = function() {
  if (clicks < 0) {
    $("h1").text("you win!");
    clearInterval(moveId);
  } else if (clicks > 0) {
    clicks--;
    speed /= 2
    clearInterval(moveId);
    moveId = setInterval(move, speed);
  }
};
$("h1").click(stopFunction);
var moveId = setInterval(move, speed);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>game
  <h1>
```

Comment: Не нужно плодить переменные. В _stopFunction_ уберите **var** из строки `var moveId = setInterval(move, speed);`

Comment: и почитайте про requestAnimationFrame

Comment: @UModel сделал как вы сказали, но не помогло.

Comment: @Nik: это потому, что кроме моего совета, ещё строчку поменяли от себя. Т.ч. мне не угнаться за вашим полётом мысли. Стар я уже...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var direction = "right"
var leftOffset = 0;
var topOffset = 0;
var speed = 100;
var clicks = 3;

var moveHeadingRight = function() {
  $("h1").offset({
    left: leftOffset
  });
  leftOffset++;
  if (leftOffset > 100) {
    direction = "down";
  }
};

var moveHeadingDown = function() {
  $("h1").offset({
    top: topOffset
  })
  topOffset++;
  if (topOffset > 100) {
    direction = "left";
  }
};

var moveHeadingLeft = function() {
  $("h1").offset({
    left: leftOffset
  })
  leftOffset--;
  if (leftOffset === 0) {
    direction = "up"
  }
};

var moveHeadingUp = function() {
  $("h1").offset({
    top: topOffset
  })
  topOffset--;
  if (topOffset === 0) {
    direction = "right"
  }
};
var move = function() {
  if (direction === "right") {
    moveHeadingRight();
  }

  if (direction === "down") {
    moveHeadingDown();
  }

  if (direction === "left") {
    moveHeadingLeft();
  }

  if (direction === "up") {
    moveHeadingUp();
  }
};

var stopFunction = function() {
  clicks--;
  if (clicks <= 0) {
    $("#test").text("you win!");
    clearInterval(moveId);
  } else {
    speed /= 2
    clearInterval(moveId);
    moveId = setInterval(move, speed);
  }
};
$("h1").click(stopFunction);
var moveId = setInterval(move, speed);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="test">game<h1>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я не до конца понимаю, что вы изменили, что бы игра заработала как надо. Можете обьяснить? Было изменено несколько вещей else if было измененно на else.(clicks < 0) на (clicks <= 0). Я не вижу как эти изменения помогли починить проблему, ведь по сути этот код делает тоже самое, что делал предыдущий код.

Comment: @Nik У Вас был пропущен случай `clicks == 0`.